# How to read Excel file from a specific storage in Android?

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi

I am working for my university project. I have searched a lot but don't know why the excel is not reading. I have added [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi/3.9) jar file in Android Studio. Followed [this](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-read-write-excel-file-using.html) tutorial. Actually I am confused. But I have added some logs and toasts as you see. They are showing nothing. I have debugged it, in fact in the case of debug, it shows nothing. Can you please suggest me a good way to read and write Excel or any code snippet?

The code is as follows:

```
    if (!isExternalStorageAvailable() || isExternalStorageReadOnly())
    {
        Log.w("FileUtils", "Storage not available or read only");
        return;
    }

    try{
        // Creating Input Stream
        sharedPreferences = MyApplication.preferences;
        final int projectID = sharedPreferences.getInt("count", 0);
        int taskID = 0;
        final String count = sharedPreferences.getString("project", projectFile);
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"
                + mainFolder + "/" + count,"/task.xls");
        Log.e("full file",file.toString());
        FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(file);
        Log.e("full file",myInput.toString());
        // Create a POIFSFileSystem object
        POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);
        Log.e("full file",myFileSystem.toString());
        // Create a workbook using the File System
        HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem);
        Log.e("full file",myWorkBook.toString());

 //       Workbook wb = WorkbookUtil.create(new File("MyExcel.xls"));

        // Get the first sheet from workbook
        HSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
        Log.e("full file",mySheet.toString());
        /** We now need something to iterate through the cells.**/
        Iterator<Row> rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();

        HSSFRow nameRow = mySheet.getRow(1);
        String name = nameRow.getCell(0).toString();
        projectname.setText(name);
        Log.e("full file",name.toString());


        while(rowIter.hasNext()){
            HSSFRow myRow = (HSSFRow) rowIter.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
            while(cellIter.hasNext()){
                HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellIter.next();
                Log.w("FileUtils", "Cell Value: " +  myCell.toString());
                Toast.makeText(context, "cell Value: " + myCell.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace(); }

    return;
```

The logs stop working after this line:

```
 FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(file);
```

Log file is:

```
11-24 12:02:46.993 9177-9196/? E/linker: "/system/bin/app_process32":  ignoring 2-entry DT_PREINIT_ARRAY in shared library!
11-24 12:02:48.055 9177-9267/? E/fb4a(:<default>):0lk: E1124  12:02:48.000000 -1703212752   xplat/liger/src/proxygen/facebook/httpclient/java/src/cpp/HTTPClient.cpp:590]    failed to get socket address from :53
11-24 12:02:48.062 9177-9267/? E/fb: failed to get socket address from :53
11-24 12:02:50.857 8986-8986/razon.language E/razon.language.Home$6: selected file /storage/emulated/0/Language/Project3/task.xls
11-24 12:02:50.857 8986-8986/razon.language E/moved: Moved To /Language/Project3/
11-24 12:02:50.862 8986-8986/razon.language E/full file: /storage/emulated/0/Language/Project3/task.xls
11-24 12:02:50.862 8986-8986/razon.language E/full file:  java.io.FileInputStream@2f04e7c
```

Comment: Did you add read storage permission? you need to also add run time permission for that in order to work from marshmallow

Comment: Yes sir, I did. I have got the run time permission at the starting of application.

Comment: What is the issue/error you are getting?

Comment: No error. The file is not reading.

Comment: How do you know that file is not reading? Why do you think so?

Comment: Actually I am confused. But i have added some logs and toasts as you see. They are showing nothing. I have debugged it, in fact in the case of debug, it shows nothing. Can you please suggest me sob good way to read and write excel or any code snippet?

Comment: does it print anything in stacktrace? `catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace(); }`. does it print atleast something in log? this log?  `Log.e("full file",file.toString());`

Comment: Log.e("full file",file.toString()); here it prints "/storage/emulated/0/Language/Project3/task.xls"

Comment: After that, it is not priniting anything, any error or log of the catch block?

Comment: No, nothing from catch block :(

Comment: At last i got the error in stacktrace, and it is "org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)
"

Comment: But i am using poi version 3.9 and xls extension. Even it didn't worked for xlsx :(

Comment: ^ Please add the new stack trace and the version information into your question, by editing it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this based on last stack trace of yours which was,

> org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException: The supplied
>   data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part
>   of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a
>   different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)

As the trace message suggests, the file you're trying to read out the data from has a format supported from Office 2007 and onwards. POI has this component named XSSF([see the very basic in first paragraph](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/)) that can be used to handle such documents.

So, technically speaking, you need to replace your `HSSFWorkbook, HSSFSheet, HSSFRow, HSSFCell` etc to `XSSFWorkbook, XSSFSheet, XSSFRow, XSSFCell`and forth on. As for the following,

```
POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);
```

`POIFSFileSystem` (or similarly, NPOIFSFileSystem) is only used with .xls documents. The equivalent for .xlsx documents is `OPCPackage`([example](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage)). It builds out of a File directly thus, your code should look like this.

```
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(file);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You could just use [WorkbookFactory](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html), and it'd take care of it for you!